# How can I use zxing to create a standalone barcode reader?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I want to make an Android app by using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). Can anyone tell me how to use the core library, or anyone know how to use the core library to build a barcode scanner?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494683/how-to-write-a-barcode-scanner-in-android-using-zxing?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call Zxing intent in your Activity and relax.

First add code to invoke the Intent:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Second, add this to your Activity to handle the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
    // handle scan result
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}
```

Invest your time to go through wiki page of Zxing.They have explained it very nicely.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/w/list

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Here is sample application demonstrating how to call Zxing intent.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/androidtest/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidtest/ZXingTestActivity.java

Finally Test Project + Library is located at

[http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%253Fstate%253Dclosed](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/android-integration%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: is it possible to scan the barcode without intent? I want to merge codes of zxing with my app. How can i know about the functional detail of zxing?

Comment: Zxing source code is available at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid

Comment: Can you tell me about encoding of barcode. Suppose i want to make a generic barcode reader and there are three scan mode qr_mode, product_mode and one_d_mode in ZXing. how can i integrate these decodings in single scan mode.